# How to fetch number of results from a Google query

Tags: php, google-api

Whilst trying to develop a keyword difficulty tool of my own ran into a problem when fetching the total number of results from a Google query. To make it as clear as possible here's a screen of the number I'm looking to fetch: [image]

I could't find any references of how to do this on the Google Custom Search API so I've built a small scraper, but I feel it's not the best method of doing it. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$keyword;
$text = file_get_contents($url);
//get string between 2 strings function
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
//fetch the string between "About" and "results"
$res = get_string_between($text, "About", "results");
//keep only numeric characters
$res = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $res);
?>
```

Can you suggest a better way of doing this? (Preferably using a Google API)

Comment: I've used this scraping approach before, but I'd caution against it. Google frequently changes the markup of their results page (I'm guessing in part because they're trying to discourage this). It is basically a violation of google's IP.

Comment: Also, there the results page sometimes has different markup for the same "block". I believe that the number of returned results has different markup depending on the number of results returned (`none` vs `10` vs `10,000`, etc)

Comment: This number is so over exaggerated I wouldn't ever use it. Ever wonder to the 'last' page of your results?

Comment: @njk I agree with you it's not a very accurate metric, but I'm also trying to fetch the number of results for the allintitle:"keyword" and allinanchor:"keyword" queries. When assessing the keyword difficulty I'm mostly looking at the number of results for these two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
$params = array('q' => 'shark with lasers that shoot monkeys with balloons on skyscrapers please give me less results asdafasddfg');
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/search?' . http_build_query($params));
preg_match('/About (.*) results/i', $content, $matches);
echo !empty($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;
// output: 14,300
```

I can't find anything in their APIs. Beware, this is against Google TOS. Bing's API will give you a result count.

Comment: I read somewhere that bing provides this number via their API, but I've noticed dramatic differences between the total number of results in google vs bing for the same query...